# How to get a previous page value

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, asp.net

Using C#,

I want to get a value from previous page.

For example,

```
In a page A i have the textbox value like "apple", i want to get the same value in page B
```

Page A Code.

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)"
    onclick="window.open('pageB.aspx',
    'Add','width=700,height=400')">
    Add</a>
```

Above Code is linking a Page B from Page A

How to get a value page A textbox value in Page B.

Need Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just pass the value as a parameter in your call to open pageB.aspx?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
    onclick="window.open('pageB.aspx?param=' +
 document.getElementById('textBoxFromPageA').value,
        'Add','width=700,height=400')">
        Add</a>
```

This will generate the URL of `pageB.aspx?param=Apple`.  Then on the pageB.aspx code behind, you can access that value using the `Request("param")` call.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe can store it in a Session-variable?

Here you can find some more information: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/165/tn_16563.html

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to query string or session consider using the PreviousPage property or using server.transfer and then getting a handle to the previous page through context.handler.

Doing this is beneficial in that session is not utilised needlessly and query string parameters: visible, editable, hackable by all of the world are not used.